# Access on-premise network from Azure spoke vnet

Tags: azure, networking, vnet

We have implemented a HubToSpoke network in azure and a VPN connection to our on-premise network like this one :

[HubToSpoke Network implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOMMF.png)

```
The network look like this:
    On-premise   <-> vnet-hub        <-> vnet-spoke
    10.88.0.0/16     10.222.0.0./16      10.221.0.0/16
```

From the on-premise netwok we can access a VM inside the HUB (and vice-versa).
From the HUB we can access a VM inside the SPOKE (and vice-versa).

We cannot access a VM from the HUB to the on-premise network (and vice-versa).

How can we achieve this ?

We have setup the peering between HUB and SPOKE following this article :
[Configure VPN gateway transit for virtual network peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-peering-gateway-transit?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json)

So peering from SokeToHub has `Use remote gateways` enabled and HubToSpoke has `Allow gateway transit` enabled.

Do we need something more ? A route table ? If yes how can I setup this ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have downloaded VPN client packages before VNet peering and enabling gateway transit, I suggest re-downloading the VPN client on the local machine to make sure that routes to the gateway-connected virtual networks or on-premises networks propagate to the routing tables.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll try this solution, and I will update this post.

Comment: Hello nancy, my collegue which handle this part is in vacation for the week, I'll update ASAP when we've updated the VPN configuration. sorry for the delay.